# javascript get object attributes in object

Tags: javascript

Let's take for example an array of objects:

```
var arrOfObjects = [{
   "@attributes":{
      "shuttle_id":"19939004",
      "date":"2021-08-30 14:04:00"
   },
   "CODE_NOT_FOUND":{
      "Code":"58182",
      "PosX":"56.6678",
      "PosY":"54.5086"
   }
},
{
   "@attributes":{
      "shuttle_id":"19939004",
      "date":"2021-08-30 14:02:00"
   },
   "DECONNECTED_ERROR":{
      
   }
}]
```

In order to retrieve the sub-elements of the array objects, I proceeded as follows:

```
arrOfObjects.forEach(objOfObjects=> {
    for(var key in objOfObjects) {
      var value = objOfObjects[key];
      console.log(value);
    }
 });
```

and the result was:

```
{
   "shuttle_id":"19939004",
   "date":"2021-08-30 14:04:00"
}


{
   "LandmarkCode":"58182",
   "PosX":"56.6678",
   "PosY":"54.5086"
}
```

I want get the object name as: `CODE_NOT_FOUND, DECONNECTED_ERROR`
Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Does `console.log(keys);` inside that loop fixes your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to obtain the keys of `arrOfObjects` as an array. Then use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to loop over those keys and return the keys except `"@attributes"`
You can try it as below

```js
var arrOfObjects = [{
    "@attributes": {
      "shuttle_id": "19939004",
      "date": "2021-08-30 14:04:00"
    },
    "CODE_NOT_FOUND": {
      "Code": "58182",
      "PosX": "56.6678",
      "PosY": "54.5086"
    }
  },
  {
    "@attributes": {
      "shuttle_id": "19939004",
      "date": "2021-08-30 14:02:00"
    },
    "DECONNECTED_ERROR": {

    }
  }
]
arrOfObjects.forEach(obj => {
  const result = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => key !== "@attributes")[0]
  console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the convention where each object has an `@attributes` and then a code inner objects, then the following code will get only the code objects and print the key and object out.

```
arrOfObjects.forEach(objOfObjects=> {
    for(var key in objOfObjects) {
      if(!key.includes('@')) {
            var obj = objOfObjects[key];
            console.log('OBJ', obj);
            console.log('KEY', key);
      }
    }
 });
```

[RunKit](https://runkit.com/dills122/inner-object-loop-example)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure of what you are trying to do, but in your "for" loop, the "key" variable is holding the name of the objects, you can use that.